# Is it a good idea to test SQL scripts by using ROLLBACK at the end of a script?

Tags: t-sql, transactions

I need to write some SQL update scripts to add tables, rename columns etc. I put everything inside a transaction:

```
IF EXISTS (/* check version */)
BEGIN
    -- print cannot apply update
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        -- apply updates

    ROLLBACK
    --COMMIT
END
```

Now if I `ROLLBACK` the updates instead of `COMMIT` them can I assume that later when I change it back to `COMMIT` it will work? I don't want to apply it to my dev database just yet but be able to press `F5` and check if everything's fine.

Comment: There are some things that a rollback will not do.  Why not create a secondary database with just the schema objects and test it there ?

Comment: @Amir Oh :-O I always thought a rollback is able to undo actually everything. I think all I would ever do in my update scripts is creating new tables, columns, renaming columns/tables, perhaps deleting something and updating the version.

Comment: Identity values assigned within the transaction are permanently consumed. Transactions are used to manage changes to data, not the schema.

Comment: I've voted for migration to [dba.se] as I suspect more useful answer-content would be generated there.

Comment: @AakashM I've been also thinking of posting it there too/instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, 
if you want to test,you must be sure of the state of your database.
Better to write a small script, which drops your tables/complete database and write some SQL which creates the database, tables and adds test data.Then you can do a real test, with SQL you really gonna use, instead arbitrary (different from the real SQL to use) SQL and wondering if any site-effects of your test code.

SSV(short-short-version): Try to execute your tests as clean as possible, witout any other test-code. which MIGHT interfere with expected results.

Comment: If it only was so easy to create a batch that runs all the update scripts after deleting everything.